# Can you specify a last step in Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I am hosting my Github Actions runners locally. I want to clean up Docker images/containers that get created every time my github action runs, and it should run whether the job fails or is killed in the middle (similar to a try/finally block). Is there anything like this?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-status-check-functions).

Answer (score 1):

You might be needed "conditional job" feature. You can define conditions for specific step if needed. Example:

```yaml
name: Cleaning
if: failure()
run: ./cleaning.sh
```

Resources:

https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#failure
https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/github_actions_13_conditionals.html